# Installing packages in R

Tags: r, swirl

I installed swirl package in R studio console and I started learning R programming. After completing a chapter I closed R studio. I didn't save the workspace while quitting the R studio.

After a day I started R-Studio again and ran swirl() command in the console. The R-Studio gave this error - "Error: could not find function "swirl""

Do I need to install the package everytime in R studio? Doesnt it store in R ? Pls help.

Comment: you install them once with `install.packages("pkg")`, but at every new session you need to load them with `library("pkg")`

Comment: No, but you have to call `library(swirl)` or `require(swirl)` to load the package whenever you start a fresh session.

Comment: Open up RStudio, type `RShowDoc("R-intro")`, press return, and then read chapter 13 of the pdf document that it opens up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should first type the command `library (swirl)`. That will load the library in the namespace and allow you to use its functions.